# What does the code print? Exercise in C

Tags: c

I am not sure why does this code print "h=13" and not "h=2". Does anyone have an idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int j,h=1;
for(j=0;j<50;j++) {
        if(j%6==1) continue;
        h++;
        if(j==7 || j==14 || j==21)
               break;
}
printf("h=%d",h);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try it yourself. If you don't have a compiler, use an online compiler.

Comment: Use breakpoints to go line-by-line

Comment: Hint: what does the expression `j%6` evaluate to when `j` is 7?

Comment: Think about what happens when `j=7` and think about what `continue` means

Comment: *'...and not "h=2"'*. What's so special about h=2? Why would this code print h=2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When `j = 0` neither of the if statements return a value of 1, and thus `h` is incremented.
2. When `j = 1` in `(j % 6 == 1)` , **1 % 6 will give a remainder of 1**. The statement `j % 6` is true and so, h is *not incremented*. (the '%' is a Remainder Operator)
3. When `j = 2` to `j = 6` neither of the if statements return a value of 1, and thus `h` is incremented.
4. When `j = 7` in `(j % 6 == 1)` , **7 % 6 will give a remainder of 1**. The statement `j % 6` is true and so, h is *not incremented*.
5. When `j = 8` to `j = 12` neither of the if statements return a value of 1, and thus `h` is incremented.
6. When `j = 13` in `(j % 6 == 1)` , **13 % 6 will give a remainder of 1**. The statement `j % 6` is true and so, h is *not incremented*.
7. For `j = 14` the statement `j == 14 is` **true** and thus the break statement is executed.

h will be incremented for : `j`= 0, `j`= 2 to `j` = 6, `j`= 8 to `j`= 12, `j` = 14 which is a total of 12 times.

Total of 12 + 1 (`h = 1`) = 13